# How to get the name and path from applescript

Tags: applescript, filenames, filepath

I have a file, say, "123.xyz", opened in TextWrangler.
How can I use Applescript to get the "its absolute path + full name" of the currently opened file.
So that I could use this in another program or script.

I modified some code I found online, but it didn't work for me.

```
tell application "TextWrangler"
    tell document 1
        -- Get (absolute path + filename) of the current file
        set FileName to «class ppth» as text
    end tell
end tell
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "TextWrangler"

    --This will return the file path of document 1 in the following format: file "Macintosh HD:Users:UserName:Desktop:document1.txt"
    set filePath1 to file of document 1


    --This will convert the file path of document 1 to the following format: "Users/UserName/Desktop/document1.txt"
    set filePath2 to POSIX path of filePath1
end tell
```

Comment: Good show! You could expand upon this by showing how to pass the filespec you've generated above to the shell for `textutil`   :)

Answer (score -1):

This **SHOULD** work:

```
tell document 1 to set myVeryOwnPath to path as text
```